# python: obtaining a column of dates from the columns of years-months-days

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a very simple dataframe:

```
>>> a
Out[158]: 
   monthE  yearE dayE
0      10   2014   15
1       2   2012   15
2       2   2014   15
3      12   2015   15
4       2   2012   15
```

Suppose that I want to create the column with the date related to every line, using three columns of integers.
When I have simple numbers it is enough to do like:

```
>>> datetime.date(1983,11,8)
Out[159]: datetime.date(1983, 11, 8)
```

If I have to create a column of dates (theoretically a very basic request), instead:

```
a.apply(lambda x: datetime.date(x['yearE'],x['monthE'],x['dayE']))
```

I obtain the following error:

> KeyError: ('yearE', u'occurred at index monthE')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can first remove last char `E` and then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), but then get  `pandas timestamps` not `python dates`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str[:-1]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df)
#if multiple columns filter by subset
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']])
print (df)
   month  year  day       date
0     10  2014   15 2014-10-15
1      2  2012   15 2012-02-15
2      2  2014   15 2014-02-15
3     12  2015   15 2015-12-15
4      2  2012   15 2012-02-15

print (df.date.dtypes)
datetime64[ns]

print (df.date.iloc[0])
2014-10-15 00:00:00

print (type(df.date.iloc[0]))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Thank you [`MaxU`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572051/python-obtaining-a-column-of-dates-from-the-columns-of-years-months-days#comment70349200_41572097) for solution:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns = lambda x: x[:-1]))
#if another columns in df
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['yearE','monthE','dayE']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1]))
print (df)
   monthE  yearE  dayE       date
0      10   2014    15 2014-10-15
1       2   2012    15 2012-02-15
2       2   2014    15 2014-02-15
3      12   2015    15 2015-12-15
4       2   2012    15 2012-02-15
```

But if really need `python dates` add `axis=1` to [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but then is impossible use some pandas functions:

```
df['date'] =df.apply(lambda x: datetime.date(x['yearE'],x['monthE'],x['dayE']), axis=1)
print (df)
   monthE  yearE  dayE        date
0      10   2014    15  2014-10-15
1       2   2012    15  2012-02-15
2       2   2014    15  2014-02-15
3      12   2015    15  2015-12-15
4       2   2012    15  2012-02-15

print (df.date.dtypes)
object

print (df.date.iloc[0])
2014-10-15

print (type(df.date.iloc[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Comment: I think we can rename columns on the fly: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns = lambda x: x[:-1]))`, so we can keep original column names