# Operation on Pandas Dataframe columns using its Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This should be relatively easy.  I have a pandas dataframe (Dates):

```
    A   B   C
1/8/2017    1/11/2017   1/20/2017   1/25/2017
1/9/2017    1/11/2017   1/20/2017   1/25/2017
1/10/2017   1/11/2017   1/20/2017   1/25/2017
1/11/2017   1/20/2017   1/25/2017   1/31/2017
1/12/2017   1/20/2017   1/25/2017   1/31/2017
1/13/2017   1/20/2017   1/25/2017   1/31/2017
```

I would like to take the difference between Dates.index and Dates.  The output would be like so:

```
    A   B   C
1/8/2017     3   12      17 
1/9/2017     2   11      16 
1/10/2017    1   10      15 
1/11/2017    9   14      20 
1/12/2017    8   13      19 
1/13/2017    7   12      18
```

Naturally, I tried this:

```
Dates - Dates.index
```

But I receive this lovely TypeError:

```
TypeError: Could not operate DatetimeIndex...with block values ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Instead, I've written a loop to go column by column, but that just seems silly. Can anyone suggest a pythonic way to do this?

EDIT

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
dates = pd.date_range('20170108',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([len(dates),3]),index=dates,columns=list('ABC'))
df['A'].loc[0:3] = datetime.date(2017, 1, 11)
df['B'].loc[0:3] = datetime.date(2017, 1, 20)
df['C'].loc[0:3] = datetime.date(2017, 1, 25)
df['A'].loc[3:6] = datetime.date(2017, 1, 20)
df['B'].loc[3:6] = datetime.date(2017, 1, 25)
df['C'].loc[3:6] = datetime.date(2017, 1, 31)

In [2]: print(df)
                     A           B           C
2017-01-08  2017-01-11  2017-01-20  2017-01-25
2017-01-09  2017-01-11  2017-01-20  2017-01-25
2017-01-10  2017-01-11  2017-01-20  2017-01-25
2017-01-11  2017-01-20  2017-01-25  2017-01-31
2017-01-12  2017-01-20  2017-01-25  2017-01-31
2017-01-13  2017-01-20  2017-01-25  2017-01-31

In [3]: df = df.sub(df.index.to_series(),axis=0)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18,) (6,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a more explicit and elegant way to do this is to simply use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

`df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, axis="columns")  # just to make sure values are datetime
df.apply(lambda x: x - df.index.to_series(), axis="rows)`

Answer (score 2):

You need first convert all columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
#if dtypes of all columns are datetime, omit it
date_cols = list('ABC')
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

df = df.sub(df.index.to_series(),axis=0)
print (df)
                A       B       C
2017-01-08 3 days 12 days 17 days
2017-01-09 2 days 11 days 16 days
2017-01-10 1 days 10 days 15 days
2017-01-11 9 days 14 days 20 days
2017-01-12 8 days 13 days 19 days
2017-01-13 7 days 12 days 18 days
```

You need `dtypes` `datetime64`:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20170108',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df.loc[0:3, 'A'] = pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 11)
df.loc[0:3, 'B'] = pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 20)
df.loc[0:3, 'C'] = pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 25)
df.loc[3:6, 'A'] = pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 20)
df.loc[3:6, 'B'] = pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 25)
df.loc[3:6, 'C'] = pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 31)
print (df)
                    A          B          C
2017-01-08 2017-01-11 2017-01-20 2017-01-25
2017-01-09 2017-01-11 2017-01-20 2017-01-25
2017-01-10 2017-01-11 2017-01-20 2017-01-25
2017-01-11 2017-01-20 2017-01-25 2017-01-31
2017-01-12 2017-01-20 2017-01-25 2017-01-31
2017-01-13 2017-01-20 2017-01-25 2017-01-31

print (df.dtypes)
A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
C    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

df = df.sub(df.index.to_series(),axis=0)
print (df)
                A       B       C
2017-01-08 3 days 12 days 17 days
2017-01-09 2 days 11 days 16 days
2017-01-10 1 days 10 days 15 days
2017-01-11 9 days 14 days 20 days
2017-01-12 8 days 13 days 19 days
2017-01-13 7 days 12 days 18 days
```

Comment: While your solution is helpful, it still loops by column, which I am specifically trying to avoid.  Is there not another way?

Comment: The loop through columns is only to convert to datetime.  If they already are datetime, then you can skip that part

Comment: It loop only for converting to datetime, better is use `parse_dates`  parameter in read_csv

Comment: Right, so my data is already in datetime format, but this solution produces the operands error... "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes"

Comment: Both, really.  I've provided an edit to the original question with some mock code.

Comment: What is `df.dtypes` ? Datetimes or objects?

Comment: It is different if use python `datetime` object and pandas `datetime`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41572097/2901002) it is better explain. But for correct working need `dtypes` as datetime.

Comment: Your post-edit solution still produces a TypeError: cannot coerce a Timestamp with a tz on a naive Block

Comment: Really interested apply solution, what is slowier and not ideal solution,  works. Small advice in future: try create sample what is similar real data. Because now in sample are not datetimes with timezones, instead there are python datetimes. So it is hard find problem with your real data, which are different. Good luck and nice day.